# JSON received is sorted but became unsorted after parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Let's say for example I received a JSON from a server:

```
{
    "20141028": "28 October 2014",
    "20141029": "29 October 2014",
    "20141030": "30 October 2014",
}
```

I log the JSON using NSLog and the result is the same. Sorted by the date.

Then I tried to parse it and put the keys and values in different arrays.

The parsed result is:

Keys:

```
[
    "20141030",
    "20141028",
    "20141029",
]
```

Values:

```
[
    "30 October 2014",
    "28 October 2014",
    "29 October 2014",
]
```

How can I remedy this? Because I want the result to be exactly as the JSON I received

Comment: Objects are like key/value maps: their properties aren't generally sorted. Can you return an array? Otherwise you'll have to sort again on the client side.

Comment: Do a search on this. Dictionaries aren't sorted.

Comment: Returning an array is actually a good idea! I didn't think of it. Thanks mate @sje397

Comment: JSON "objects" are unordered.

Comment: Questions edited @HotLicks

Comment: You want what you can't have.  There is no guarantee that the next JSON payload you get will be in the same order.

Comment: See the accepted answer. It's good enough for me @HotLicks

Comment: Well, I had assumed that if all you wanted was to sort the data, you'd know how to do that.  I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort the keys and store in array. wherever you wanna display the values trying mapping with keys in array.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayList;
arrayList =[[[arrayDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

then get the value from dictionary using

```
[arrayDict objectForKey:arrayList[0]];
```